# How to save a buffer (not shown as XML to the user ) in XML format - in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to show a normal buffer to the user but I want to save what s/he has written in XML format. can I do this in anyway in Emacs? Using some function or etc?

NOTE:

normal buffer: Text without markup ... vs. ...
XML format: a file that has XML tags and ll the content of the file/buffer are stored as records ..

Comment: What do you mean by normal format vs XML format. They are both just text files. Do you mean change the major-mode form XML? The format of the file, according to emacs is dictated by the file extension or header.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr: I have added a note to the question, thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It saves transform buffer in the file with extra suffix `.xml`

```
(defun transform-file-on-save ()
  (let ((bufer-as-string (buffer-string))
    (new-file-name (concat  (buffer-file-name) ".xml")))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert bufer-as-string)
      ;; some operations in the buffer
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (replace-string "(" "<b>")
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (replace-string ")" "</b>")
      ;; save file
      (message "Writing file: %s" new-file-name)
      (write-region (point-min) (point-max) new-file-name nil 'quietly))))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'transform-file-on-save)

;; better have it around to get rid of the hook
;;(remove-hook 'after-save-hook 'transform-file-on-save)
```

Answer (score 3):

Emacs provides action hooks you can attach functions to. In this case you probably want to attach something to the `before-save-hook` which will transform the file when you save it.

```
(defun some-transform () ... )

(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'some-transform nil t)
```

I don't really know enough about your problem to say more.

The issue here is that this is a literal transform, once the user saves the file it won't change back unless you apply another transform.

In this case you will want to hook on the `find-file-hook`

```
(defn some-reverse-transform () ... )

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'some-reverse-transform)
```

which changes the xml back into flat text.

Comment: Great advice man. My main problem is the actual conversion of the buffer content to an XML type file. I mean storing "TEXT TEXT" as "<XML> <content attribute="text"> TEXT TEXT </content> </XML>.. can you advice me about that too mate?

Comment: So you can do that with the transform function. It would be a bit annoying / take a nice chunk of code but you can have emacs output XML compliant strings.